# Seeding a faker command with laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

Just trying to do a quick Faker + Seeder, in my UsersTableSeeder:

```
public function run()
{
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
    $email = $faker->email;

    for ($x = 1; $x >= 5; $x++) {
        'name' => $faker->firstName . ' ' . $faker->lastName,
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => password_hash($email, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
    }
}
```

but when I'm about to run `php artisan db:seed`

it returns a

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)
```

Am I a missing something out here? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it all wrong, just realize it

`User::create([])` and it should be `<=`

Thanks for hearing me out guys.

Comment: mark as correct or close